# Зависимые переменные в разных пространствах

Tags: c++, объявление, стандарт

Почему программа выводит 01, а не 00?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A {
extern "C" int x = 0;
};

namespace B {
extern "C" int x;
};


int main() {
    std::cout << B::x;
    A::x = 1;
    std::cout << B::x;
}
```

Comment: А почему она должна выводить `00`? Где обоснование ожидаемого поведения? Без него ваш вопрос звучит как "почему в программе 2+2 равно 4, а не 5".

Answer (score 3):

Программа выводит `01` потому что она и должна выводить `01`. Спецификация языка [ясно говорит](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#6)

> Two declarations for a variable with C language linkage with the same name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that appear in different namespace scopes refer to the same variable.
>
> Два объявления переменных с C-линковкой с одним и тем же именем (игнорируя квалифицирующие его имена пространств имен), которые располагаются в разных пространствах имен, ссылаются на одну и ту же переменную.

Оба объявления - `A::x` и `B::x` - объявляют одну и ту же переменную.

---

Сама постановка вопроса несколько удивляет. При каких это обстоятельствах можно ожидать от такой программы вывода `00`? Если бы `A::x` и `B::x` объявляли разные переменные? Но тогда программа вообще бы не скомпилировалась из-за отсутствия определения для `B::x`.

Answer (score 0):

`extern "C"` портит все :) - по сути вы в двух пространствах имен объявляете единственную переменную `x`, которая, будучи `extern "C"`, ничего не знает о пространствах имен...

Попробуйте определить вторую переменную - ну, типа

```
namespace B {
    extern "C" int x = 3;
};
```

и вы получите соответствующие сообщения при компиляции.